# How do you flip and rotate NetCDF (.nc) files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, latitude-longitude, netcdf, rotate

I am trying to extract Surface PM2.5 values from the NetCDF files available on the Atmospheric Composition Analysis Group's website. However, when I load it into QGIS, it appears to be flipped and rotated. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have imported the nc file as a raster layer. Then, there is a SAGA **Transpose raster layers** tool in the `QGIS Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Raster tools`.

This tool swaps *X* and *Y* axis of the input raster.

[image]